# Linux Mint: How to launch a new version of a program

Tags: linux, installation, linux-mint, application-launch

I'm running Linux Mint and an application called anki (flash card app). The software repositories for Linux Mint are a few versions behind. When I download the new program it just runs from the directory. The problem is that when I launch it from the menu it opens the old version, not the new. I placed the folder in /usr/share/anki-1.2.9/, the old version is located in /usr/share/anki/. I tried replacing /usr/share/anki with the contents of anki-1.2.9 but then it wouldn't launch.

What I'm missing is how to tell the system to use "/usr/share/anki_1.2.9/" instead of "/usr/share/anki/" when the command, "anki" is executed. I'm fairly new to Linux but I'm sure it's something simple like editing a file in a directory somewhere. I just have no idea which file and where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a running Linux Mint here but if you're using Gnome you should be able to do a right click over the menu icon (the icon you click to access the app list) and select "Edit Menus". There you can edit the old menu entry and point it to the new version.

Comment: I did try that. It runs the command, "anki %f" which launches the original version. I need it to launch the new version when that command is done. But thanks.

Comment: try by entering the full path or change the path variable to include the directory in which the new binary is located.

Comment: I knew I would be something totally obvious, thanks.